# read and echo .txt file is giving UNDEFINED OFFSET ERROR in php

Tags: php, error-handling, fopen

First of all, I need to say that I have found same type of question in this site. I followed some of the solutions, but didn't work in my case.

I have a .txt file that I need to echo out in specific order. Here is the .txt file.

```
Question1|opt1,opt2,opt3;Question2|opt1,opt2,opt3;Question3|opt1,opt2,opt3;
```

Here is the code

```
$open=fopen("mydata.txt","r+");

$blocks = explode(';', file_get_contents('mydata.txt'));

foreach($blocks as $block)
{

  list($question, $opts) = explode('|', $block);  //LINE 'X'
  $opt = explode(',', $opts);
  $eco=$question."</br>".'<input type=radio>'.$opt[0].'<input type=radio>'.$opt[1].'<input type=radio>'.$opt[2];  //LINE 'Y'
  echo $eco;

}

fclose($open);
```

Gives me 3 Undefined offset Notice for LINE X(1 Notice) and LINE Y(2 Notice). And, gives me 3 extra radio button with blank values.

Need help in this issue.

Comment: your text file is in UTF-8 encoding ?

Comment: @Juck Not an expert.So,no idea about UTF-8 encoding

Comment: when you open your text file with notepad (from windows) , and you "save as" you can choose the encoding , by default on Windows it's ANSI , try to put UTF-8 and overwrite the file.

Comment: I have done as suggested,but still giving same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution for this problem.

Using multidimensional array works in this case.What I have done is insert contents as arrays and retrieve content from that.

It is working now.